# difficulty with javax.swing.Timer

Tags: java, swing, timer, jpanel, actionlistener

I have a runtime error when I press the tick button. I am trying to use javax.swing.Timer when the tick  button is pressed to fire an event So if anyone have any suggestions I would appreciate them. I am currently using Eclipse and there is a runtime error when the tick button is pressed.

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.Error: Unresolved
>   compilation problem: The type ClockPanel must implement the inherited
>   abstract method ActionListener.actionPerformed(ActionEvent) at
>   ClockPanel.actionPerformed(ClockPanel.java:10)

Here is the code I am using (3 classes).

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

class Clock 
{
     int hour;
     int minute;
     int second;

     Calendar gregcal = new GregorianCalendar();
     int h = gregcal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
     int m = gregcal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
     int s = gregcal.get(Calendar.SECOND);

    //default constructor
    Clock()
    {
        hour = h;
        minute = m;
        second = s; 
    }

    //parameterized constructor
    Clock(int hour, int minute, int second)
    {
        this.hour = hour;
        this.minute = minute;
        this.second = second;      
    }

    public int getHour()
    {
        return hour;
    }

    public int getMinute()
    {
        return minute;
    }


    public int getSecond()
    {
        return second;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return "The time is: " + hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second ;    
    }   

    public void tick()
    {
        second += 1;
        if(second > 60)
        {
            second = 0;
            minute++;
        }
        if(minute > 60)
        {
            minute =0;
            hour++;
        }
        if(hour > 24)
        {
            hour = 0;
        }
        System.out.println(this.toString());
    }
}

// next class


import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

import javax.swing.*;

public class TestClock 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Calendar gregcal = new GregorianCalendar();
        int h = gregcal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int m = gregcal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        int s = gregcal.get(Calendar.SECOND);

        Clock c = new Clock(h, m, s);

        JFrame application = new JFrame("Clock");
        ClockPanel panel = new ClockPanel(c);

        application.add(panel);
        application.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        application.setSize(160,80);
        application.setVisible(true);  
    }

}


// the last class here is the problem
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.Timer;

class ClockPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener
{
    Clock myck = new Clock();
    private javax.swing.Timer timer;
    JTextField txt1, txt2, txt3;
    JLabel  jl1, jl2;
    JButton tick;
    JPanel top, buttom;



    ClockPanel(Clock ck)
    {

        this.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));
        top = new JPanel();
        top.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,5));

        String hour  = "" + ck.getHour(); // easier way  
        txt1 = new JTextField(hour);
        top.add(txt1);

        jl1 = new JLabel(" : ");
        top.add(jl1);

        String minute = Integer.toString(ck.getMinute()); // harder convertion
        txt2 = new JTextField(minute);
        top.add(txt2);

        jl2 = new JLabel(" : ");
        top.add(jl2);

        String second = Integer.toString(ck.getSecond());
        txt3 = new JTextField(second);
        top.add(txt3);
        this.add(top);


        buttom = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,1));


        tick = new JButton("tick");
        buttom.add(tick);
        tick.addActionListener(this);
        this.add(buttom);

    }

    javax.swing.Timer t = new javax.swing.Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {



    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) 
    {

        if(ae.getSource().equals(tick))
        {

            myck.tick();
            txt1.setText(Integer.toString(myck.getHour()));
            txt2.setText(Integer.toString(myck.getMinute()));
            txt3.setText(Integer.toString(myck.getSecond()));   
        }   
    }
    });
    public void start()
    {
        t.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: um... what is the error message?

Comment: sorry I forgot about that  here is it

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 The type ClockPanel must implement the inherited abstract method ActionListener.actionPerformed(ActionEvent)

 at ClockPanel.actionPerformed(ClockPanel.java:10)

Comment: Also, I see no actionPerformed method for the ClockPanel class. Yes, there's an anonymous ActionListener added to the Timer, but the scope of that actionPerformed method is of the anon ActionListener, not the ClockPanel class, and so I don't see how this code compiles.

Comment: Then the problem is just what I stated above. You must give ClockPanel an actionPerformed method that is for use by the tick button.

Comment: well I am using eclipse and it running the program when i press tick button is giving me the error from the top

Comment: But surely Eclipse is showing compilation errors, no? Isn't the class name underlined in red with a red error marker in the left margin? It should give you this error: "The type ClockPanel must implement the inherited abstract method ActionListener.actionPerformed(ActionEvent) TestClock.java

Comment: it is actually and cheers mate

Answer (score 5):

As per my comments, your problem is that you must give your ClockPanel class an actionPerformed method that is in the scope of this class. You shouldn't even be trying to run a class that doesn't compile, but rather should fix all compilation errors first before trying to run the code.